# Differential equation $\left(x^2+xy\right)y'=x\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+xy+y^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure which type of differential equation this falls into:

$$\left(x^2+xy\right)y'=x\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+xy+y^2$$ any hints? P.S. I first tried reornazing it so I have $y'$ alone, and hoping that I would get a homogeneous equation, but no such luck.

Comment: Divide $x^2$ from both sides and then let $z=\dfrac{y}x$. Then, $y'=z+xz'$.

Comment: The new equation becomes $(1+z)y'=\sqrt{1-z^2}+z+z^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide both side to the $x^{ 2 }$ $$\left( x^{ 2 }+xy \right) y'=x\sqrt { x^{ 2 }-y^{ 2 } } +xy+y^{ 2 }\\ \left( 1+\frac { y }{ x }  \right) { y }^{ \prime  }=\sqrt { 1-\frac { { y }^{ 2 } }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  } +\frac { y }{ x } +\frac { { y }^{ 2 } }{ { x }^{ 2 } } \\ y=zx\\ { y }^{ \prime  }={ z }^{ \prime  }x+z\\ \left( 1+z \right) \left( { z }^{ \prime  }x+z \right) =\sqrt { 1-{ z }^{ 2 } } +z+{ z }^{ 2 }\\ { z }^{ \prime  }x+z+z{ z }^{ \prime  }x+{ z }^{ 2 }=\sqrt { 1-{ z }^{ 2 } } +z+{ z }^{ 2 }\\ { z }^{ \prime  }x\left( 1+z \right) =\sqrt { 1-{ z }^{ 2 } } \\ \int { \frac { \left( 1+z \right) dz }{ \sqrt { 1-{ z }^{ 2 } }  }  } =\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } $$
substitute now :$z=\sin { \theta  } $
$$\int { \frac { 1+\sin { \theta  }  }{ \cos { \theta  }  } \cos { \theta  } d\theta  } =\ln { Cx } \\ \theta -\cos { \theta  } =\ln { Cx } \\ \arcsin { z-\sqrt { 1-{ z }^{ 2 } }  } =\ln { Cx } $$
so the final aswer is :

> $$\arcsin { \frac { y }{ x }  } -\frac { \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }-{ y }^{ 2 } }  }{ x } =\ln { Cx } $$

Comment: thank you very much mister

Comment: would you use euler substitution to solve that integral?

Comment: try  substite $z=\sin { \theta  } $

Comment: Our results are different... could you point out my mistake?

Comment: I did and it worked out fine,  I then proceeded to rewrite 1 as sin^2+cos^2 and write 2sinxcosx then subtract sinxcosx as a separate integral and it was rather easy to solve, however when are such trig subs appropriate is there a pattern to them so I  can spot them easier P.S. here we can't use sec,csc functions.

Comment: @triniggaalculuscalca,it was my fault i fixed now

Comment: @KennyLau,i made a mistake,thanks,i fixed it

Answer (score -2):

Divide $x^2$ from both sides and then let $z=\dfrac{y}x$.

Note that $y'=z+xz'$.

The new equation becomes $(1+z)y'=\sqrt{1-z^2}+z+z^2$.

$y'=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}}+z$

$x\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}}$

$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{x}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}}\ \mathrm dz$

$\ln(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac1{1-z}}\left((z-1)\sqrt{z+1}+2\sqrt{1-z}\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+z}}{\sqrt2}\right)\right)+C$

And... it gets too complicated.